# Почему не удаётся получить имена и тип элементов корневого каталога FTP сервера?

Tags: c#, ftp

Использую библиотеку ByteRoad.Net.Ftp.dll для работы с QNX сервером. Получаю список файлов через метод GetDirectoryList(), но все имена элементов равны null и их тип равен Unresolved. У FTP клиента включен пассивный режим.

```
FtpItem[] ftpItems = _client.GetDirectoryList(_timeoutFtp);
```

- ftpItems[0]: Name = null, ItemType = Unresolved
- ftpItems[1]: Name = null, ItemType = Unresolved
- ftpItems[2]: Name = null, ItemType = Unresolved

Comment: Как вы поняли, что вы и правда получаете список файлов, если в нем только одни null? Кстати, протокол FTP уходит в прошлое, в первую очередь из-за сетевых проблем. Я использую SFTP (типа FTP через SSH) уже несколько лет, проблем не видел. Так что если ваш сервер поддерживает SSH, то рекомендую использовать SCP/SFTP для передачи файлов. Для C# есть библиотека SSH.NET, есть плагин для Total Commander, приложение WinSCP и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую воспользоваться другой библиотекой. А что на счёт списка, то я вижу права доступа каждого полученного элемента.